# TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null. at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, button, hyperlink, addchild

Created a button, now tried to add it to the screen and im getting this error. The code for the button is -

```
private function submitButton():void {
  submit_button=new SimpleButton();
  submit_button.x=200;
  submit_button.y=200;
  submit_button.upState=buttonShape();
  submit_button.overState=buttonShape();
  submit_button.downState=buttonShape();
}

private function buttonShape() {
  var rectangle:Shape = new Shape; // initializing the variable named rectangle
  rectangle.graphics.beginFill(0x8C2B44); // choosing the colour for the fill, here it is red
  rectangle.graphics.drawRect(200, 200, 300,20); // (x spacing, y spacing, width, height)
  rectangle.graphics.endFill();
}
```

I've declared it as a public var and I'm using `addChild(submit_button);`

- edit - all the code is in one class file. i set the submit button at the start, - private var submit_button:SimpleButton; i have a function private function submitButton():void {
          submit_button=new SimpleButton();
          submit_button.x=200;
          submit_button.y=200;

  ```
      submit_button.upState=buttonShape();
      submit_button.overState=buttonShape();
      submit_button.downState=buttonShape();

  } and the drawing function seen above. and i add it to the stage in another function  - private function gameOver():void {

      addChild(submit_button);
      addChild(gameOver1);      basically this function is called on a hit test. and i have a text box that appears (this works) but when i add the button i get the error
  ```

Comment: where are you using addChild(submit_button)? Also, where do you initially declare the instance variable for it? Outside of that function I assume? Like, var submit_button:SimpleButton; near the top of the class constructor?

Comment: I think the buttonShape() should return the var rectangle

Comment: yeah got this at the top of the class file - private var submit_button:SimpleButton; and what do you mean @chchrist by returning the var rectangle?

Comment: put "return rectangle" at the end of the buttonShape() and see if this fixes the problem. You draw the shape but then you don't return it in order to assign it to a variable

Comment: ive added return rectangle to the statement. It still gives the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `buttonShape()` isn't returning anything. Your inital line `var rectangle:Shape = new Shape;` is creating a local variable, which goes out of scope and ceases to exist at the end of the function.

As `buttonShape()` doesn't return anything, it's actual function signature is:

```
private function buttShape():void {}
```

with a `return void;` being implied at the end of the function.

This means that your code

```
submit_button.upState=buttonShape();
```

is essentially compiling to:

```
submit_button.upState=null;
```

Comment: ive added return rectangle to the statement. It still gives the error

Comment: can you post the code where you declare `submit_button`, call the `submitButton()` function and add it to the stage? I've just taken the code you posted and it's working on my end

Comment: you need to check that `submitButton()` is actually getting called before `gameOver()`. for a quick test, just call `submitButton()` directly before the line `addChild(submit_button);`